# Angular 8 <mat-checkbox> aparece siempre el círculo como que ha cambiado de true a false o viceversa

Tags: angular, angular-material

Buenas tardes estoy teniendo un problema acabo de incorporar los  a mi proyecto y aparece siempre el círculo como que lo he pulsado y nunca se quita.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del frontal donde llamamos al checkbox.

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <ui-input-checkbox name='Activo' [(ngModel)]="verificationDto.activeId"></ui-input-checkbox>
                </div>
```

Esta es la clase del ui-input-checkbox

```
<div class="mat-input-flex mat-form-field-flex">
    <div class="mat-form-field-prefix" [ngStyle]="{'width' : labelWidth ? labelWidth : '' }">
        <label matPrefix>{{labelWidth !== '0%' ? name+': ' : ''}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mat-input-div">
        <div class="mat-input-input" >
                <mat-checkbox
                  [(ngModel)]="value"
                  [id]="identifier"
                  [disabled]="disabled || disabledByState"></mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <validation [@flyInOut]="'in,out'" *ngIf="(invalid | async) && model.dirty" [messages]="failures | async"></validation>
</div>
```

He mirado con la versión de angular y coincide con todo lo que tengo. Estoy en la 8.1

Comment: Mariete, tienes que entender que más allá que digas que todo coincide con su documentación oficial, es necesario verificar el código... Siempre hay algún margen de equivocación tuya o nuestra... Si nos muestras tu código nos será mucho más simple analizar y encontrar un posible error... Sin eso simplemente estamos trabajando a ciegas

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes intentar relacionándolo a un [(ngModel)] al cual su valor inicial sea 'false' un ejemplo:

```
ngOnInit() {
     book.checked = false;
}


<mat-checkbox (change)="activateBook($event, book)" matTooltip="Activo" [(ngModel)]="book.checked">Activar Libro</mat-checkbox>
```